# Django basic authentication in functional View

Tags: python, django, django-views, basic-authentication, tastypie

I am looking to apply an Basic Authentication mechanism to the functions in my view functions.

I have some view functions that return JSON data via a template. If I visit my app via a webrowser, I want to be prompted with a login dialog, otherwise the Authorization header is used for RESTFUL API

I have looked at the TastyPie documentation and I cannot find any examples of how I would use it this way.

For instance in view.py file I have the following:

```
def userIndex(request):
    some_list = Some.objects.order_by('pub_date')

    return render_to_response('myapp/data.json',
                          {'some_list': some_list,},
                          mimetype="text/json")
```

How would I apply the authorization check to the above?

Comment: how do you call your view through ajax?

Comment: it would be nice if tastypie had a built in way to decorate your functions (i don't know if they do), but if worst you can easily write a decorator using their code https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/authentication.py#L75

Comment: I am using calling view a URL in urls.py

Comment: If I had decorator, that would be ideal.. I will look at the code and see if I can implement my own (although I would prefer something off-the-shelf and reliable)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to distinguish between a browser visit and an API call. If you follow HTTP basic auth specification, browsers will display login dialog without your view doing anything special.

And here is a decorator that implements basic auth check: http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/243/. It checks username/password against a standard User table.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. I previously used this. But I found it was slowing down my request's response quite considerably (Not sure why). I am just wondering if there was another decorator

Comment: As far as I know, Django does not ship with any implementation of basic auth, you need to find some external one. I'm not sure how much this implementation slowed down your view, I guess it performs two additional DB queries: one to sessions table and one to users table, which introduces some overhead, but it is unavoidable if you want to take credentials from a db. You can also consider enabling basic auth in the frontend server (nginx or apache). It will for sure be much faster, but you won't be able to use Django usernames and passwords.

Comment: Hi, I enabled basic auth in my front end server in the end... Seems to work fine. Thanks